# Проблема с sender() в PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, сигналы-слоты, sender

У меня возникает проблема при попытке получить сигналы, которые возникают при нажатии кнопок. 
Все 12 кнопок подключены к методу `add()`, при нажатии на кнопку должен срабатывать `print(self.sender().text())`, но у меня просто крашится программа.

Проблема именно `self.sender().text()`, всё остальное работает так, как надо.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        self.action = ""
        self.result = 0
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(316, 313)
        self.textBrowser = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(Form)
        self.textBrowser.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 291, 51))
        self.textBrowser.setObjectName("textBrowser")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 90, 41, 41))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 90, 41, 41))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 90, 41, 41))
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 140, 41, 41))
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.pushButton_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 190, 41, 41))
        self.pushButton_5.setObjectName("pushButton_5")
        self.pushButton_6 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 140, 41, 41))
        self.pushButton_6.setObjectName("pushButton_6")
        self.pushButton_7 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 140, 41, 41))
        self.pushButton_7.setObjectName("pushButton_7")
        self.pushButton_8 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 190, 41, 41))
        self.pushButton_8.setObjectName("pushButton_8")
        self.pushButton_9 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton_9.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 190, 41, 41))
        self.pushButton_9.setObjectName("pushButton_9")
        self.pushButton_10 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton_10.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 240, 41, 41))
        self.pushButton_10.setObjectName("pushButton_10")
        self.pushButton_11 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton_11.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 240, 41, 41))
        self.pushButton_11.setObjectName("pushButton_11")
        self.pushButton_12 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton_12.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 240, 41, 41))
        self.pushButton_12.setObjectName("pushButton_12")
        self.pushButton_13 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton_13.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 190, 141, 91))
        self.pushButton_13.setObjectName("pushButton_13")
        self.pushButton_13.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {background-color: rgb(255, 36, 0); color: White; border-radius: 8px;}"
                           "QPushButton:pressed {background-color:rgb(31, 101, 163) ; }")

        self.pushButton_14 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton_14.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 90, 141, 91))
        self.pushButton_14.setObjectName("pushButton_14")
        self.pushButton_14.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {background-color: rgb(11, 218, 81); color: White; border-radius: 10px;}"
                           "QPushButton:pressed {background-color:rgb(31, 101, 163) ; }")
        
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {background-color: rgb(66, 170, 255); color: White; border-radius: 4px;}"
                           "QPushButton:pressed {background-color:rgb(31, 101, 163) ; }")
        self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {background-color: rgb(66, 170, 255); color: White; border-radius: 4px;}"
                           "QPushButton:pressed {background-color:rgb(31, 101, 163) ; }")        
        self.pushButton_3.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {background-color: rgb(66, 170, 255); color: White; border-radius: 4px;}"
                           "QPushButton:pressed {background-color:rgb(31, 101, 163) ; }")        
        self.pushButton_4.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {background-color: rgb(66, 170, 255); color: White; border-radius: 4px;}"
                           "QPushButton:pressed {background-color:rgb(31, 101, 163) ; }")        
        self.pushButton_5.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {background-color: rgb(66, 170, 255); color: White; border-radius: 4px;}"
                           "QPushButton:pressed {background-color:rgb(31, 101, 163) ; }")
        self.pushButton_6.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {background-color: rgb(66, 170, 255); color: White; border-radius: 4px;}"
                           "QPushButton:pressed {background-color:rgb(31, 101, 163) ; }")        
        self.pushButton_7.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {background-color: rgb(66, 170, 255); color: White; border-radius: 4px;}"
                           "QPushButton:pressed {background-color:rgb(31, 101, 163) ; }")
        self.pushButton_8.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {background-color: rgb(66, 170, 255); color: White; border-radius: 4px;}"
                           "QPushButton:pressed {background-color:rgb(31, 101, 163) ; }")        
        self.pushButton_9.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {background-color: rgb(66, 170, 255); color: White; border-radius: 4px;}"
                           "QPushButton:pressed {background-color:rgb(31, 101, 163) ; }")
        self.pushButton_10.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {background-color: rgb(66, 170, 255); color: White; border-radius: 4px;}"
                           "QPushButton:pressed {background-color:rgb(31, 101, 163) ; }")        
        self.pushButton_11.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {background-color: rgb(66, 170, 255); color: White; border-radius: 4px;}"
                           "QPushButton:pressed {background-color:rgb(31, 101, 163) ; }")
        self.pushButton_12.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {background-color: rgb(66, 170, 255); color: White; border-radius: 4px;}"
                           "QPushButton:pressed {background-color:rgb(31, 101, 163) ; }") 
        
        self.textBrowser.setStyleSheet("QTextBrowser {background-color: rgb(250, 250, 250); color: White; border-radius: 10px;}")
        
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.add)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.add)
        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.add)
        self.pushButton_4.clicked.connect(self.add)
        self.pushButton_5.clicked.connect(self.add)
        self.pushButton_6.clicked.connect(self.add)
        self.pushButton_7.clicked.connect(self.add)        
        self.pushButton_8.clicked.connect(self.add)
        self.pushButton_9.clicked.connect(self.add)        
        self.pushButton_10.clicked.connect(self.add)
        self.pushButton_11.clicked.connect(self.add)
        self.pushButton_12.clicked.connect(self.add)
        

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "9"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Form", "8"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("Form", "7"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("Form", "6"))
        self.pushButton_5.setText(_translate("Form", "2"))
        self.pushButton_6.setText(_translate("Form", "5"))
        self.pushButton_7.setText(_translate("Form", "4"))
        self.pushButton_8.setText(_translate("Form", "3"))
        self.pushButton_9.setText(_translate("Form", "1"))
        self.pushButton_10.setText(_translate("Form", "0"))
        self.pushButton_11.setText(_translate("Form", ","))
        self.pushButton_12.setText(_translate("Form", "+/-"))
        self.pushButton_13.setText(_translate("Form", "Стереть"))
        self.pushButton_14.setText(_translate("Form", "Равно"))
        
    def add(self):
        print(self.sender().text())    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Замените `print(self.sender().text())` на `print(Form.sender().text())`

Comment: О, спасибо большое. Всё заработало, как я сам до этого не догадался, совсем невнимательным стал :(